# Bar chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts, html5-canvas

The following code is my attempt to create a bar chart with javascript and  the html 5 canvas:

```
var canvas = $("#chart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeFill = "green";
var margin = 5;
var bWidth = (canvas.width - (margin * results.length)) / results.length;
var max = results.sort()[results.length - 1];
var yScale = canvas.height / max;
for (result of results)
{
    ctx.strokeRect();
}
```

The data I am trying to visualize looks like this:

```
[{"choice": "Yes", votes: 2}, {"choice": "No", votes: 1}, {"choice":"maybe", votes: 3}]
```

The questions are:

- How can I compute the x and y axes for each element?
- How can I print the choices under the bars?
- There can be up to 20 choices and each can be up to 200 characters. How could this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

After additional research the following is the solution:

```
var results = extractResults($("#results"));
var canvas = $("#chart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var margin = canvas.width * 0.005;
var bWidth = (canvas.width - (margin * results.length)) / results.length;
var max = Math.max.apply( Math, results );
var yScale = canvas.height / max;
var currX = margin;
ctx.font = "20px Arial"
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
{
    var bHeight = yScale * results[i];
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(currX, canvas.height - bHeight, bWidth, bHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(i + 1, currX + bWidth / 2, canvas.height - canvas.height * 0.05, bWidth / 2);
    currX += bWidth + margin;
}
```